# Spark streaming does not read files moved from HDFS to HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a simple WordCount program. Spark Streaming is watching a directory in HDFS for new files and should process them as they come in.

I start my streaming job, I add a bunch of small files to a *tmp* HDFS directory, then I move these files to the watched HDFS directory (all with simple shell command, *-mv*). But my streaming job is not recognizing these as new files and therefore not processing them (I checked that the files are well moved).

Currently I am using textFileStream but am open to using fileStream. I'm using 1.3.1 or 1.4.0 Spark version.
I'd like to mention that with the 1.0.x version of spark, all's well (it detects new -moved- files) !

The code is:

```
//files are moved from /user/share/jobs-data/gstream/tmp to /user/share/jobs-data/gstream/streams, both directories are on HDFS.

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass().getName())
sparkConf.setMaster(master)
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Milliseconds(1000))
val data = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)) //args(1) == /user/share/jobs-data/gstream/streams
val words = data.flatMap(.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey( + _)
wordCounts.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Could anyone have some ideas, thanks ?

Comment: Please post your code. Otherwise we're just guessing what you're done

Comment: In fact, the code is a simple word count:
        val data = ssc.textFileStream(args(1));
        val words = data.flatMap(_.split(" "));
        val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _);
        wordCounts.print();

Comment: Edit the code into your question, please. Are both your watched directory and tmp directory on the same file system? "Files must be written to the monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same file system".  Maybe your tmp is somewhere different.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and added some other details

Comment: I take it there's a `ssc.start` in there somewhere? And can you show the code that sets up `ssc`?

Comment: Are the files copied with the right privileges?

Comment: Yeah, I copy them with the right owner and the right privileges

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that FileInputDStream uses modification time to find new files. But if a file was moved into the directories its modification time would not be changed, so FileInputDStream could not detect these files.

A way to solve this problem is that you can use some way to change modification time, such as use "copy" to instead "move".

Comment: No, you definitely can't copy the files.  The doc very specifically says you have to move them.  But you can touch them to update the timestamp before you do the move.  That solved my problem (cat > /some/file/in/hdfs; touch /some/file/in/hdfs; move /some/file/in/hdfs /location/that/is/watched).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code :

```
    val fstream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](hdfsPath, (f: Path)
                     => true, newFilesOnly=false).map(pair => pair._2.toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the similar problem.

In my case the problem was that I copied the file *before* starting the `StreamingContext`, but it picks only files created *after* starting it.

Try to copy the file in different folder after starting `StreamingContext` and then move it to the folder that you scan.